# Can my company spy on me using antitheft software like Prey?

Tags: spyware, keylogger, anti-theft

I'm a tech guy and I have my company Macbook with me at all the times. My company encourages me to use it as much as possible (even for my private tasks).

I know all the Macbooks we own have Prey preinstalled, I'm wondering if the CTO can spy on me using Prey? If yes what sort of data can he get and how can I tell what Prey sends to him? For example can he see what websites I visit (even if I use incognito mode)? Or what files I do have on my disks? Luckily it's pretty obvious when the camera is on, but how about the microphone? The thought of ripping me off my privacy is scary.

I know Prey is a great piece of software and doesn't spy on you per se, but that's a totally different story if you're not the one who installed Prey in the first place.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you asking about Prey specifically, or _any_ software?

Comment: I'm not saying that the likelihood that your employer will decide to is high, but if someone else owns and administers the computer you are using you should always assume that they have the capability to know all of that.

Comment: If you are worried then you should uninstall `Prey` or don't use the company laptop for personal business.

Comment: I'm asking about Prey specifically. I can't uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

from the site

> > Will Prey spy on me?
>
> No. As long as you don’t send the activation signal to your PC or
>   phone, Prey will sleep calmly without doing a thing. And when you do,
>   it will only gather the information you request and send it. Not a bit
>   of data is gathered without your consent.

so the answer is no unless they decide to spy on you then yes it will.

Comment: Your single sentence doesn't make sense considering its a  contradiction with itself.  I suggest finding a better way to respond.

Comment: That was the point of the sentence.

Comment: The point is I'm not the one in charge of sending the activation signal.

Comment: if you're not in charge of the signal then the answer = yes simple as that

Comment: The problem is even if I don't use the laptop for personal stuff I can still be spied on using in-built microphone, camera and so forth. I can't uninstall Prey, is there anything I can do to see if my company actually spies on me using Prey? What kind of info can Prey give to them?

Comment: If you are really this concerned about it just keep the laptop in a box when you are not at work. Better yet, if it is disturbing you this much I think there is a degree of trust that is missing between you and your employer that would make you enjoy your job much more and maybe a different job is the best answer.

Comment: If you were particularly clever you could just block incoming traffic from prey or wherever they data to activate orginates

Answer (score 1):

> What about running Prey on a device someone else uses? Is that a
>   violation of privacy?
>
> Good question. First of all, if the device doesn’t belong to you, you
>   should immediately remove Prey as that is not only a violation of
>   privacy but also a violation of our Terms of Service. Now, if the
>   device is indeed yours (i.e. company, school, university, etc) then
>   the answer really depends on the privacy laws in your country.

So **yes**, if Prey is installed, it is possible for whoever owns the account it is associated to, to use whatever features it has while the end user is using the machine.

As an IT security advocate, I'd be nervous about a company installing tracking software on a machine and then *encouraging* me to use it for *personal* tasks. The benign implication is that they really are using Prey just as an anti-theft tool, and you aren't being monitored at all; the more onerous possibility is that Prey *is* being used to monitor those "personal" activities.

So basically, **it's possible**. Are they actually doing it? You probably won't know. So, it's up to you to decide where on that spectrum you're going to stand.